# warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces] (IN MACRO)

Tags: c, gcc, struct, initialization

I'm trying to initialise the structure element with the default values using a macro. Unfortunately, I'm continuously getting a warning whose resolution I'm unable to find yet, can anyone help me to understand what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Note:

1. I'm getting Warning at the time of initialisation.
2. I've tried both macros but still not able to resolve
3. compiling code with GCC compiler on Linux based operating system.

```
/******MACROS DEFINITION******/ /*headers.h*/

#define  _dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01 (stProcessFile_ALL){ .filePTR1=-1 , .fileBuff1="\0" , .fileName1 = "temp1.txt"}

//#define  _dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01 (stProcessFile_ALL){ .filePTR1=-1 , .fileBuff1={"\0"} , .fileName1 = {"temp1.txt"}}


/******STRUCTURE DEFINITION******/ /*headers.h*/
typedef struct
  {

    FILE filePTR1;
    FILE filePTR2;
    FILE filePTR3;

    char fileBuff1[500];
    char fileBuff2[500];
    char fileBuff3[500];                                    

    char *fileName1;
    char *fileName2;
    char *fileName3;                

  }stProcessFile_ALL;


/******STRUCTURE INIT******/

void FnLaodDeFaultValue (uint8_t ucStrSelec)
{

stProcessFile_ALL stVarProcessFile_ALL;
stVarProcessFile_ALL = _dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01 ;

}
```

COMPILER:

```
gcc -Wall -o "Main" "Main.c" "process.c" "-lwiringPi" "-pthread"  (in directory: /home/pi/Desktop/CombinerCARD)

In file included from process.c:16:

process.c: In function ‘FnLaodDeFaultValue’:

headers.h:65:34: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]

#define  _dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01 (stProcessFile_ALL){ .filePTR1=-1 , .fileBuff1="\0" , .fileName1 = "temp1.txt"}

process.c:184:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘_dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01’
   stVarProcessFile_ALL = _dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01 ;
```

Comment: `FILE* filePTR1;` and others. `_dfLOAD_DEFAULT_FILE01` requires a parameter, according to #define.

Comment: @S.M. No, the macro does not need a parameter.

Comment: OP, please don't edit your code in a way that removes the whole problem you're asking about.

Comment: thanks, my problem is resolved with this

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is this part:

```
.filePTR1=-1
```

`filePTR1` is declared as

```
FILE filePTR1;
```

and `FILE` is a struct type, so this is trying to initialize a struct without `{ }`. That's what the warning is about.

You probably meant to use

```
FILE *filePTR1;
```

instead, making `filePTR1` a pointer.

But note that `-1` is not a valid pointer value either.